# I already registered in Dailymotion and create apiKey, then how do I generate sampleapp.properties file?

Tags: android, dailymotion-api

There is a block code in `build.gradle` file:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream("sampleapp.properties"))

buildConfigField "String", "apiKey", props.getProperty("apiKey")
buildConfigField "String", "apiSecret", props.getProperty("apiSecret")
buildConfigField "String", "defaultLogin", props.getProperty("defaultLogin")
buildConfigField "String", "defaultPassword", props.getProperty("defaultPassword")
```

I clone dev version from github, and when I open the sampleapp in Android studio, gradle building failded because of missing `sampleapp.properties` file.

I already registered in `Dailymotion` and created a apiKey for my application.
Now my question is how to generate a `sampleapp.properties` file so that gradle building would be successful?

Thank you.

Comment: Which project have you cloned? Which error do you when you build your gradle file?

Comment: dailymotion-sdk-android-dev is what I clone.

Comment: dailymotion-sdk-android-dev is what I clone.
The error I got is 
Error:(24, 0) Cause: sampleapp.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
<a href="openFile:C:\Software\Dailymotion\dailymotion-sdk-android-dev\sampleapp\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `project.rootProject` if you are reading the properties file in a sub-project `build.gradle`:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(project.rootProject.file('sampleapp.properties').newDataInputStream())
// your code goes here
```

Project structure

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle <-- You are reading the sampleapp.properties in this gradle build file
│   └── src
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
├── gradlew
├── settings.gradle
└── sampleapp.properties
```

**UPDATE**
Your `sample.properties` file should look like shown below, just with your own values:

```
apiKey="yourKey"
apiSecret="yourSecret"
defaultLogin="yourLogin"
defaultPassword="yourPassword"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me, but it generated same error becasue there is no "sampleapp.properties" file existing in the higher level folder.
The error is
Error:(25, 0) C:\Software\Dailymotion\dailymotion-sdk-android-dev\sampleapp.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: you have to create this file by yourself

Comment: @HuangZou I have updated my answer and added `sample.properties` file

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I need! This error is solved now.